# Specify jQuery UI Tooltip CSS styles

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am using jquery ui 1.9 in an ajax based website.

I have the following code:

```
This is a <span title="Some warning" class="warning">warning</span> message<br />
This is a <span title="Some info" class="info">info</span> message
```

Using jquery ui tooltip would work, even for dynamic content:

```
$(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
});
```

But I want different tooltip styles for each of this message-types. For example red color for warning and blue for info and it should work for dynamic content too.

Any ideas?

Comment: you might be interested in the ajax widget see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175268/ajax-content-in-a-jquery-ui-tooltip-widget

Comment: and look at the code on this page http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/tooltip/tooltip-empty-after-postback-when-dynamically-added-in-a-custom-webcontrol.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your post, but thats not what I am looking for. I don't want to load the content of the tooltip with ajax. I want to have tooltips ON dynamic content and there should be different tooltip styles for different clesses (like info, warning, etc..)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery ui tooltip custom class on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054294/jquery-ui-tooltip-custom-class-on-page-load)

Answer (score 13):

You need to use the [toolTipClass](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-tooltipClass) property to specify the css class

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".warning" ).tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "warning-tooltip"
    });
    $( ".info" ).tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "info-tooltip"
    });  
});
```

Comment: NB The `tooltipClass` method is now deprecated in favour of using the `classes` option to specify additional styles, as of jQuery UI 1.12:
http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-classes

Answer (score 7):

First, here is the code that works:

```
$(function() {
    $('#warning-binder-element').tooltip({
        items: '.warning',
        tooltipClass: 'warning-tooltip',
        content: function () {
            return $(this).prev('.warning-toast').html();
        },
        position: {
            my: "right bottom",
            at: "right top-10"
        }
    });

    $('#info-binder-element').tooltip({
        items: '.info',
        tooltipClass: 'info-tooltip',
        content: function () {
            return $(this).closest('.doo-hicky').next('.info-toast').html();
        },
        position: {
            my: "left bottom",
            at: "left+10 top-10"
        }
    });  
});
```

A few notes on the above:

- The selector for `.tooltip()` is not the item you want to have a tooltip pop up on, it is an element on the page that the tooltip object and its associated events are bound to.
- If you attempt to bind two tooltips to the same object, only the last one will persist so binding both to `$(document)` will not work (which is why I have bound the two different tooltip objects to two different elements on the page).
- you can bind the tooltip object to the item that will get the tooltip, but if you use a class selector, this may lead to ill effects.