# How to use jQueryUI tootip along with my custom css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using jQueryUI tooltip & custom css to format it. Tooltip is coming but not able to aply my css class on top of it.
Code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#roles").tooltip({ content: "Start typing a name for the IT role you're staffing. There are 75 to choose from. If you're uncertain, start with something general like '<i>Manager</i>'" });    
});
```

HTML

```
<input id="roles" type="text" class="wGridPx_16"/>
```

CSS

```
<style>
        .ui-tooltip
        {
            font-size: 11px;
            color: #fff;
            text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
            padding: 4px 8px;
            border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
            background-color: rgb(25,25,25);
            background-color: rgba(25,25,25,0.82);
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(transparent), to(#000));
            border-radius: 3px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 3px #555;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #555;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #555;
        }
    </style>
```

Please help. I have checked many Q/A blogs on it like [jquery ui tooltip custom class on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054294/jquery-ui-tooltip-custom-class-on-page-load) but nothing helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [tooltipClass](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-tooltipClass) option

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#roles").tooltip({
        content: "Start typing a name for the IT role you're staffing. There are 75 to choose from. If you're uncertain, start with something general like '<i>Manager</i>'",
        tooltipClass: 'my-class'
    });

});
```

then

```
.my-class.ui-tooltip {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
    background-color: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.82);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(transparent), to(#000));
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #555;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #555;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #555;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9sY3c/)