# Apply CSS to JQuery tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I try to apply a CSS to all the tooltip on my `html` page but can't find the way to do it.

I have done my research and found some results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054294/jquery-ui-tooltip-custom-class-on-page-load), and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780759/overriding-css-styles-of-the-jquery-ui-tooltip-widget) for instance, but can't make it work.

Here is part from my `html` page:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 text-center" title="Tooltip title"> </div>
```

And since I reference all the `tooltips` on this page:

```
(function (window, $) {   
    // Set the Tooltips
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).tooltip({
            tooltipClass: "tooltip-styling"
        });
    });
})(window, $);
```

`tooltip-styling` is the following `CSS class`:

```
.tooltip-styling{
    background-color:red !important;
    color: red !important;
}
```

Nothing fancy, just wanted to check if the style is applied.

As you have guessed, it is not.

What should i do more?

Comment: `$('.selector').tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "tooltip-styling",
});`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding CSS styles of the jQuery UI Tooltip widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780759/overriding-css-styles-of-the-jquery-ui-tooltip-widget)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fitting your case, the css declaration you have to overwrite is "background" and not "background-color".

https://jsfiddle.net/nrnLgc36/1/

*html*

```
<div class="col-sm-3 text-center" title="Tooltip title">TEST</div>
```

*css*

```
.tooltip-styling{
    background:green !important;
    color: black !important;
}

.col-sm-3 {
  display: block;
  background: #bacd63;
}
```

*javascript*

```
(function (window, $) {

    // Set the Tooltips
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).tooltip({
            tooltipClass: "tooltip-styling"
        });
    });
})(window, $);
```

Comment: That was it ... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$( ".selector" ).tooltip( "option", "tooltipClass", "custom-tooltip-styling" );
```

As explained here: [Here](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-tooltipClass)

Comment: I think it is exactly the same as my code, isn't it?