# Tooltip using jquery ui

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

Its my first time using the tooltip and have done a lot research on it. I used the jquery website  to get most of the information. I intend my tooltip to show dynamic data when a mouse clicks the  hyperlink. I added the title to my link and have this code below:

```
  var t = 1000;
     $(document).tooltip({
       content: '... waiting on ajax ...',
open: function(evt, ui) {
    var elem = $(this);
    $.ajax({ type: "POST",url:'/GetTooltip/', data: 80140}).always(function() {

        elem.tooltip('option', 'content', 'Ajax call complete');

     });
setTimeout(function(){
  $(ui.tooltip).hide('destroy');
   }, t);},

   position: {
    my: "center bottom-20",
    at: "center top",
    using: function( position, feedback ) {
      $( this ).css( position );
      $( "<div>" )
        .addClass( "arrow" )
        .addClass( feedback.vertical )
        .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
        .appendTo( this );
    }
  }

});
```

I am not fully knowledgeable with the syntax of the ajax call in reference to the always function and how to get the data to show on my tooltip. the GetTooltip returns JSON data, I just want to post to the GetTooltip script and the returned data to show on my tooltip. At the moment my ajax is posting nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your statement that you are not fully knowledgeable with

- always function: the always(function(data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown) { }); is always executed after the ajax request was executed. For more see the documentation  [deferred.always()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) Please look also at [`jqXHR.always(function(data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown) { })`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- get the returned data to show on the tooltip - see the example in the fiddle

You can find many [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175268/ajax-content-in-a-jquery-ui-tooltip-widget) on stackoverflow. Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvHT3/) and let me know if you need more help.

#### Updated fiddle 2

If have [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvHT3/231/). You can pass values from the parameters that are returned from the ajax callback. This is a simple wrapper around the ajax call:

```
function callAjax(elem){
    $.ajax({ url: '/echo/json/',
         type: 'POST',
         contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType:"json",
         data:  { json: JSON.stringify({ text: 'some text'})}
      }).always(
          function(data,textStatus, errorThrown) 
          { 
             elem.tooltip('option', 'content'
                , 'Ajax call complete. Result:' + data.text);
           });
}
```

I am using `JSON.stringify(...)` above to create a Json-String. This function may be not present in all browsers. So if you run into troubles please use a current chrome / chromium browser to test it.

So you can use the wrapper function inside the tooltip():

```
$('#tippy').tooltip({
    content: '... waiting on ajax ...',
    open: function(evt, ui) {
        var elem = $(this);
        callAjax(elem);
    } // open
});
```

Above you can see that the always method calls an anonymous function with 3 parameters (data, textStatus, errorThrown). To pass the reply from the ajax call you can use `data`. Above i am only passing a simple object with the propert text. To access it you can use `data.text`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Where do I pass the value which need to be executed in the GetTooltip script? Thanks for the links, I am looking at the always function now.

Comment: @SitheloNgwenya i have updated the fiddle and the explanation. Let me know if you need more pointers.

Comment: Your code is great. I have marked as answered. I am looking at the updated code now.