# jQuery UI Tooltip - how to apply to dynamically added elements (not mouseover and mouseenter)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to apply jQuery tooltip to dynamically added elements?

I do not want to use mouseover and mouseenter, because most of the time this doesnt show the tooltip on first try.

I also do not want to reapply the tooltip after every ajax call, because this has been throwing weird opacity errors in my application (even when i destoryed them before every call).

Is there any other sophisticated way to apply the tooltips?

Thanks

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.element-has-tooltip', function(){

    $(this).tooltip({
        items: $(this),
        content : function(){

                return $(this).find('.global-tooltip').html();

            },
        position:{
            my: "center bottom",
            at: "center top",
        },
    })

})
```

Comment: If the plugin doesn't support it, sticking the plugin inside an event handler sure won't help.

Comment: have you tried the jQueryUI tooltip? it works great

Comment: Yeah sorry, I am talking about jQuery UI Tooltip ofc

Comment: oh right so what did you do in the ajax, can't you just set the element title attribute to what you want the tool tip to be?

Comment: As you can see in the code bit I provided, I am not using the title attribute but a div.global-tooltip html...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175268/ajax-content-in-a-jquery-ui-tooltip-widget

Comment: Nope, I do not want to do AJAX request for each tooltip on the page, no. I have the tooltips already in place, I just want to display them. The problem is that with mouseover and mouseenter its not displayed unless you hover for 2nd time (70% of the time).