# How to popup content in relative to a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to make a grid of multiple divs. I want to popup some content in any other div. But this popup content should be exactly over the div that is being hovered. It should be dynamic for each div.

I found an example [here](https://psyplay.cf/genre/action/). Please help me implement such a system.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please keep in mind that SO is a Q&A site with a set of rules, not a free coding service. So please take a https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and do your best to improve your post (use the edit button). Basically, you should show some attempts of yours and ask about a specific problem you have encountered. Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can you position relative and absolute property to overlay div just over any particular div.

please note parent div should be relative and child/overlay div should be absolute.

have a look below example.

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
.div{
  width:300px; 
  height:500px; 
  float:left; 
  margin:10px; 
  padding:10px; 
  position:relative; 
  color:#000;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.div h1{ 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
  font-size:17px;
}
.overlay-div{
  position:absolute; 
  top:0; 
  left:0; 
  padding:10px; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; 
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8); 
  color:#fff; 
  opacity:0; 
  visibility:hidden; 
   -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition:all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition:all 0.5s ease;
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
}

.div:hover .overlay-div{
  opacity:1; 
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>overlay inside div</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="div">
    <h1>div content will be here</h1>
    <div class="overlay-div">Overlay Content will be here</div>
  </div>
  
   <div class="div">
    <h1>div content will be here</h1>
    <div class="overlay-div">Overlay Content will be here</div>
  </div>
  
   <div class="div">
    <h1>div content will be here</h1>
    <div class="overlay-div">Overlay Content will be here</div>
  </div>
  
   <div class="div">
    <h1>div content will be here</h1>
    <div class="overlay-div">Overlay Content will be here</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I am very thankful to you for reply. Actually my desired structure is [link(http://gostream.site/) I do not want to overlay on the image. I want to popup out an other div which may be below the footer. Please check the source of above website that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify how you want it to happen I'd advise using jQuery UI.

You might find some examples using the Tooltip here: [jQuery UI Tooltip Example](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#default)

If you want something to happen at every other element you might want to take a look at the `:odd`-Selector of jQuery: [jQuery :odd Selector Reference](https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/)

Your grid could be created using css-grid-propertys. You can find a guide here: [grid-guide by CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

If you have more specific questions you might want to ask them in a more specific way.

Comment: Yes, this is something helpful but title attribute is limited. I want to popup much data. Please check the [http://gostream.site] when you hover over any movie. You get a popup which shows some information. I want to make exact like this.

Comment: You can use any HTML in your tooltip. Check the example "Custom content" at the link I provided. You might also be interested in retrieving the data dynamcally from the server. Then this question might be interesting for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175268/ajax-content-in-a-jquery-ui-tooltip-widget